# problem to add fetched async data to array with Object.keys method?

Tags: arrays, object, foreach, async-await, return

I am writing a function that should take a object of Animal ids, and based of the key in that object make requests to an api and fetch data that is related to that keyvalue ( e.g: the id).

The problem is that when i try to push the fetched dog and cat to a array, i cant get the objects to be displayed outside of the Object.keys().foreEach loop.

How do i return the fetched data in my animals array?

```
const animalIds =  {
   dogId: "11111",
   catId: "22222",
 };


const findData = async (animalIds) => {

let animals = [];

Object.keys(animalIds).forEach(async (key) => {
   const id = relatedTo[key];
   if (key === 'dogId') {
     const dog = await api.getDog(id);
     animals.push(dog)
   }

   if (key === 'catId') {
     const cat = await api.getCat(id);
     animals.push(cat)
   }
 });
 // console.log(animals) is an empty []
 return animals 
}
```

i am using await findData(animalIds) when i call the function.

Comment: does `getDog` and `getCat` return a promise ?

Comment: They return a promise, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.forEach(async (key) => {` does not wait for the functions to finish, it just starts them. What you need is a `map` with an `await Promise.all()`, like this:

```
await Promise.all(Object.keys(animalIds).map(async (key) => {
   const id = relatedTo[key];
   if (key === 'dogId') {
     const dog = await api.getDog(id);
     animals.push(dog)
   }

   if (key === 'catId') {
     const cat = await api.getCat(id);
     animals.push(cat)
   }
 }));
```

This starts all functions at once (same as with forEach), then it waits for all of them to finish before moving on. This way the `animals` array contains the results.